# What is the number of Partitions allowed in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Is it okay to have large number of partitions in cassandra?
Will heap memory bloat?

Comment: Since this isn’t programming related, it should probably be moved to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, Cassandra can support (Murmur3 partitioner) +/- 2^63 partitions. That comes out to a total of about 18.4 quintillion.  So no worries there, that’s perfectly fine.

> Will heap memory bloat?

No.  One, there’s a pre-set size for your heap, and it won’t get any bigger than that.  Two, Cassandra doesn’t keep all data or even all keys in memory.

You can configure how many keys/rows are cached on a per-table basis.  Just make sure not to cache more than the heap-newgen or the heap can “thrash” (constantly running GC).